# Logging into Google with curl?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, curl, command-line

I'm working on a project with Google App Engine.  I am using continuous integration via Travis, and wish to be able to deploy directly from it.  Due to a bug that [will not be resolved directly](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/389), I **can't** rely on Travis' built-in GAE deployment, so I basically have to use `mvn appengine:update` manually.  This requires me navigate to a generated URL and **manually paste to the terminal** an authentication code, which I can't do in automated builds.

It was suggested to me, however, that I do some Unix magic instead.  While I can easily pick out the URL I need to navigate to from `grep`, I still need to log in to Google with my credentials in order to actually get the authentication code (which I can then `grep` out and pipe to the deployment program).

Given that, **how do I log in to Google with my credentials, using only `curl` or similar command-line utilities?**

Comment: Maybe you could use the gcloud sdk to deploy from the command line. When I init "gcloud init" a project from the command prompt it lets me authenticate with a google account

Answer (score 1):

I've accomplished similar things in the past using Service Accounts. These are likely a good fit for your problem.

Service Accounts will allow you to authenticate and upload your app without manual intervention.

## Overview

A Service Account will allow you to do "passwordless" authentication like you may already do with `ssh`, and `git`, etc. by setting up your keys. This will remove the requirement that you log in manually, or follow the road to madness by trying to do a "manual" login automatically.

There are basically two steps:

1. Create your service account and key (with the right permissions)
2. Use that credential instead of what you're doing now

## Resources

I think it's better to give a list of resources than concrete instructions since it's basically impossible to express concisely (even though it's a simple process, there's bound to be a lot of little things that annoy), everyone's requirements will be slightly different, and Google is likely to change the process at some point.

- [Using the Google Cloud Platform Console for App Engine | Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/console/#permissions)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview)
- [Setting up OAuth 2.0 | Service Accounts](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#serviceaccounts)
- [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)

Hopefully that's enough to get you headed in the right direction.

## Note

You'll likely have to spend some time looking at your `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` and sorting out a variety of other annoyances, but I believe that this approach is the best way to solve your problem.

It sounds like you have a pretty straight-forward setup and that a Service Account alone will get you there, but if you need to get a little weird, [the App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/) is always there.